# Filter hash keys of certain length?

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to figure out a line of code to be able to do this. I have a hash that I would like to be able to pick out all of the keys that are at least 6 characters long.

Comment: Your title and question are at odds with each other. The title refers to _values_ whereas the question text refers to _keys_. It would help greatly if you edit your question using the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: "can't seem to figure out" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: "I would like to be able to pick out all of the keys that are at least 6 characters long" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: I see you joined SO just two days ago. I'm surprised your username had not been taken long ago.

Answer (score 5):

Try this one

```
your_hash.keys.select { |k| k.length >= 6 }
```

Answer (score 1):

as you want "length of values"

```
{a: 'carl', b: 'steve'}.map {|k, v| v.size }
# => [4, 5] 
# select sizes values directly  within the hash enumeration

{a: 'carl', b: 'steve'}.values.map {|v| v.size }
# => [4, 5] 
# convert hash to array of values and then select the sizes values

{a: 'carl', b: 'steve'}.values.select {|v| v.size > 4 }
# => ["steve"] 
# convert hash to array of values and then select values that has a condition
```

if you want more advanced topic on "Lazy" Enumeration http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/28-ruby-enumerable-enumerator-lazy-and-domain-specific-collection-objects

Comment: not sure what lazy enumeration has to do with this question especially since the OP currently cannot determine how to appropriately loop through a simple Enumerable.

Comment: agree, for this dude the first part is enough. For folks googling "Filter hash keys/values of certain length?" I want to provide bigger picture => lazy enumeration.